# Remote desktop minimize fails when in full screen (Windows 7 locally and remote)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, fullscreen

I recently have a problem with Remote Desktop (RD) on Windows 7. When I am in a RD session in full screen and click on the "minimize" button on the RD toolbar, the screen flickers, but the window does not go away. The only way to minimize for me is to first click on "restore" and then on "minimize" in the non-fullscreen RD session.

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and it coincided with me altering the Windows 7 performance settings for "Best Performance". The item that caused my problem was "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing".

To fix:

1. Go to Control Panel,
2. System,
3. Advanced System Settings,
4. (Performance) Settings.
5. Click the Custom button, then tick the 2nd option from the top. I was immediately able to minimize RDP windows.

Comment: On my PC, the "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing" was already enabled. Still, disabling the option and re-enabling the option fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>: Switch the client computer between a window and a full screen.

Comment: That works, however, that is not what I want. I want to go directly from fullscreen to minimized. That is what is broken.

Comment: Try to do control-alt-leftarrow or control-alt-rightarrow but it hink this might only work for xp

Answer (score 1):

Try using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> , it opens up the original desktop, Choose task manager and switch to window you want.

was quick trick for me.

Answer (score -2):

I am not doing Windows-7 to Window-7, but am using RDP from Windows-7.  To minimize my desktop I move the mouse of the top of the screen in the middle.  This gives me the connection bar from which I can minimize my remote desktop.  You can pin the connection bar on the screen if you want.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The problem was not how to find the minimize button, but that it is not working. So this answer doesn't add anything useful.